# image overwriting existing html objects

Tags: javascript, html, overwrite

i tried to generate img tag with javascript
(when clicked on link, image is created)
The problem is that when the image is generated, all other objects(other images or text) are overwritten and i cannot reach them anymore

i have something like

```
document.getElementById("picturediv").innerHTML=picturetag;
```

in html

```
<div id="bigger">
<div id="picturediv"></div>
<div id="div for some other stuff"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, unless picturetag is breaking the html.

```
<div id="bigger">
<div id="picturediv"></div>
<div id="div for some other stuff"></div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("picturediv").innerHTML="<img src='"+pictureLocation+"'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the `innerHTML` indeed "overwrites" any previous content of the element.

To append the image to the existing contents have:

```
document.getElementById("picturediv").innerHTML += picturetag;
```

Assuming `picturetag` contains valid HTML - if no luck please post more code especially what is `picturetag` and how it's created.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  document.getElementById('picturediv').appendChild(picturetag);
```

That will append the image to the div